# How to move windows forms from Visual Studio 2010 to Visual Studio 2012

Tags: forms, visual-studio, window

Well, the title says it all,

I already have a complete project in Visual Studio 2010 and I would like to copy the windows forms from there to a new project in Visual Studio 2012. 
I try to copy-paste the forms, but it wouldn't load the buttons, textbox ...
There was just some blank forms whit nothing on it

Thanks for your replies  :)

Comment: Did you copy also the Designer.cs file with the same name of your form file?

Comment: yes I did ..all of it

Comment: Try to remove the form from the VS2012 project and, after been sure that all the designer.cs or resx files are in the same directory of your form to import, add the form with the project menu

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just copy the `Form` files (`TheForm.cs` and `TheForm.designer.cs`) to the new project, then add them to the project.

Note that you will also need to move any files that form depends upon (if any) before it will work properly.

Comment: @NedimFazlić Did you move the designer file too?

Comment: @NedimFazlić Did you move all of the resources?  Why not just copy the whole project, if you're moving a lot of things, or build a library?

Comment: That's the answer ... I just load the project with vs 2012 and made some changes ... and guess what? it worked ... sorry for the truble guys :)